# How to call a C++ class instance from firefox-addon / js-ctypes?

Tags: javascript, c++, firefox-addon, jsctypes

I've got a DLL (with c++ code like that):

```
MyObject::MyObject(TYPEPERIPH typePeriph) {
    m_TypePeriph = typePeriph;
    //..
}

CR MyObject::GetTypePeriph( TYPEPERIPH *typePeriph ) const throw(MY_Exception) {
    *typePeriph = m_TypePeriph;
    //..
    return 0;
}
```

Which is called in C++, like that :

```
MyObject MyObject((TYPEPERIPH)myTypePeriph);
MyObject.GetTypePeriph(&result);
```

I'd like to call this DLL with js-ctypes :

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");
var dll = ctypes.open("my.dll");

var constructor = dll.declare('MyObject',
    ctypes.default_abi,
    ctypes.voidptr_t,
    ctypes.uint8_t
);

var ptr=constructor( 1 ) // ptr seems to be a pointer to an instance

// but how to call this instance ?? should I pass the ptr somewhere ?
var GetTypePeriph = dll.declare('GetTypePeriph',
    ctypes.default_abi,
    ctypes.int,
    ctypes.uint8_t.ptr
);

var result=ctypes.uint8_t(0);
GetTypePeriph(result.address());
myPerif= result.value;
```

The first part works (^^) ... "ptr" seems to be a valid pointer. But I can't figure out how to call the instance method with this pointer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the VTABLE then create an instance see here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Examples/Using_COM_from_js-ctypes

I also did some COM just last week with js-ctypes, I was using the DirectShow API on Windows - https://github.com/Noitidart/ostypes_playground/commits/audio-capture

The VTBLE methods MUST be in order!! That took me like two months to figure out when I first got into it.

Here are the definitions of a bunch of COM stuff I did: https://github.com/Noitidart/ostypes/compare/fb1b6324343d6e19c942bbc0eb46cfcfbe103f35...master

I edited your code to look more like it should:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/ctypes.jsm");
var dll = ctypes.open("my.dll");

var MyConstructorVtbl = ctypes.StructType('MyConstructorVtbl');
var MyConstructor = ctypes.StructType('MyConstructor', [
    { 'lpVtbl': MyConstructorVtbl.ptr }
]);
MyConstructorVtbl.define([
    {
        'GetTypePeriph': ctypes.FunctionType(ctyes.default_abi,
            ctypes.int, [           // return type
                MyConstructor.ptr,  // arg 1 HAS to be ptr to the instance EVEN though your C++ above doesnt show this. this is how it works.
                ctypes.uint8_t.ptr
            ]).ptr
    }
]);

var constructor = dll.declare('MyObject',
    ctypes.default_abi,
    MyConstructor.ptr.ptr,
    ctypes.uint8_t
);

var ptr=constructor( 1 ) // ptr seems to be a pointer to an instance
var instance = ptr.contents.lpVtbl.contents;

var result=ctypes.uint8_t(0);
instance.GetTypePeriph(ptr, result.address());
myPerif= result.value;
```

Comment: Regarding the order of API in the vtable ... Should it match against the public methods of the class ? My .h starts with the constructor, then the destructor, the first method is at the 3rd place ... should I declare them (constructor & destructor) too in the vtable ? thanks in advance

Comment: That's an awesome question @manatlan - I'm not sure. If you can please test and let me know that would be awesome. The way to test is by testing the return value of the function defined in your ctypes vtable. If it matches what you expect. For the test you can force the middle function to return `45` or something. I do know that whatever methods your class inherits, has to be in order as well. So if it inherits methods from something called `IUknown`, you look at that class and list this methods first in the order they are in at `IUnknown`.

Comment: I don't have the sources of the dll (only .h), I can't add a method ;-( ... I'm trying, and trying ;-)

Comment: @manatlan in that case just see if the result of the first public method is what you expect. That's how I did it. I use system api's, never my own, so if the pointer was wrong I would be like ok this isnt right.

Comment: I tried and tried ... I've made a lot of firefox crashs ;-)
I wanted to cancel ...
And for my last attempt, I tried https://github.com/ochameau/jscpptypes, and it works like a charm ! Great !
Thanks for your patience !

Comment: Oh wow that is very very interesting. I have been looking for a way to use that repo of jscpptypes, may you please share your work with me, I would love to update the documentation for jscpptypes here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes

Comment: There is also a new abi which might help I'm not sure about it yet - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=552533 @manatlan

Comment: Yes I've seen ^^^, but I target Firefox v20 ;-(

Comment: Hey @manatlan can you please show how you use jscpptypes, I am extremely interested to learn how to use it.